# Editing a row using Struts 2 and Hibernate is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am not able to edit table using struts2 hibernate. In Apache console I can see that the update query is executed but from table its just deleting the data and while trying to insert it getting inserted in a new row not in the same row. Can anyone please help what is wrong in this code

DAO for edit:

```
public static boolean update(trainee p)
{
    Boolean a=false;
    Session session=new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory().openSession(); 
     Transaction tp=session.beginTransaction();  
     trainee u=(trainee) session.get(trainee.class, p.getId());
     if(u!=null)
     {
     u.setAddress(p.getAddress());
     u.setPhone(p.getPhone());
     u.setAge(p.getAge());
     u.setTname(p.getTname());
     u.setGender(p.getGender());
     u.setTechnology(p.getTechnology());
     u.setEmail(p.getEmail());
     session.update(u);
     }
     tp.commit();
     System.out.println("Command successfully executed....");
     session.close();
     if(tp != null){
        a=true;
    }
           return a;
}
```

Action class:

```
public String update()
{
    String x="input";
    trainee u=new trainee();
    u.setId(id);
    u.setAddress(address);
    u.setPhone(phone);
    u.setAge(age);
    u.setTname(tname);
    u.setGender(gender);
    u.setTechnology(technology);
    u.setEmail(email);
    if(RegisterDao.update(u))
        {
        x="success";
        }
    return x;
}
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="update" class="com.ilp.action.taineeAction" method="update">
            <result name="success" type="redirect">TraineeRegistration.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">ViewTrainees.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

TraineeRegistration.jsp

```
<s:form action="traineeReg">
<s:textfield label="TraineeName" name="tname"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield label="Email Id" name="email"></s:textfield>
<s:radio name="gender" list="{'Male','Female'}"></s:radio>
<s:textfield label="Age" name="age"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield label="Phone Number" name="phone"></s:textfield>
<s:textarea label="Address" name="address"></s:textarea>
<s:select name="technology" list="{'Java','J2ee','Dot Net','Oracle'}" headerKey="" headerValue="Select" label="SelectTechnology" />
<s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  
<hibernate-configuration>  

<session-factory>  
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/javadb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>  
    <property name="connection.password">cis@123</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
<mapping class="com.ilp.bean.trainee"/>  
</session-factory>
```

viewtrainee.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>List Of Trainees Registered</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1px>
<tr>
<th>Trainee Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Ph No</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Technology</th>
<th>Edit</th>
<th>Delete</th>
<s:iterator value="contactList">
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="tname" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="email" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="gender" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="age" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="phone" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="address" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="technology" /></td>
        <td><a href="update?id=<s:property value="id"/>">edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="delete?id=<s:property value="id"/>">delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>

<a href="TraineeRegistration.jsp">Add Trainee</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show `ViewTrainees.jsp` ?

Comment: @NaMaN I have added view trainee.jsp

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the `id` property in the action. Once property is set with the value of the object you get in the hibernate session you can bind the hidden field to this property using OGNL.

```jsp
<s:form action="traineeReg">
<s:hidden name="id" value="%{id}"/>
<s:textfield label="TraineeName" name="tname"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield label="Email Id" name="email"></s:textfield>
<s:radio name="gender" list="{'Male','Female'}"></s:radio>
<s:textfield label="Age" name="age"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield label="Phone Number" name="phone"></s:textfield>
<s:textarea label="Address" name="address"></s:textarea>
<s:select name="technology" list="{'Java','J2ee','Dot Net','Oracle'}" headerKey="" headerValue="Select" label="SelectTechnology" />
<s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

When you call `u.setId(id);` the value should be already there.

You should also modify the code to able to insert a new record.

```java
 if (p.getId() != null) {
  trainee u=(trainee) session.get(trainee.class, p.getId());
  u.setAddress(p.getAddress());
  u.setPhone(p.getPhone());
  u.setAge(p.getAge());
  u.setTname(p.getTname());
  u.setGender(p.getGender());
  u.setTechnology(p.getTechnology());
  u.setEmail(p.getEmail());    
  session.update(u);
 } else session.save(p);
```

Comment: Here I agree with you for Id property but if id is null then it should create a new record   as she has added not null condition like below.    trainee u=(trainee) session.get(trainee.class, p.getId());
     if(u!=null)

Comment: @Ranjitsinh Updated to insert a new record.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I have tried to modify both TraineeRegistration.jsp and DAO class as per code updated above but still I am getting the same error. When I click edit in the table , it will delete all the data leaving a blank row and the new data I inserted it is added as a  new row. I could not find out what is the issue.

Comment: @Neelam Baruah Can you please provide sample code of hibernate cfg configuration?

Comment: @Ranjitsinh I have added hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: @Ranjitsinh what may be the issue then? I am not able to resolve yet

Comment: @NeelamBaruah You don't understand that you should set the id property in the list objects and when action is executed get the id from the property of the action. That's what I meant *the value should be already there*.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Your problem is when you click on update link on success you are opening `TraineeRegistration.jsp` and in this jsp you have defined `<s:form action="traineeReg">` so after filling form when you click on submit button it will fire new insert action associated with `action="traineeReg"` and it will insert data as new row.

What you can do is you can create one more action `EDIT` and in that action write code to fetch data of selected id and than pass that data to jsp and fill form with existing values than on submit write code to update data: Following code will help you to get particular data of ID:

EditAction.java

```
public String edit()
    {
        SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session s = sf.openSession();

        Query q = s.getNamedQuery("findbyid").setInteger("id", getId());
        al = (ArrayList<User>)q.list();

        return"success";
    }
```

To use `namedquery` you need to add following code into your `name.hbm.xml` after end of class tag `</class>`.

```
<query name="findbyid">
    <![CDATA[from User u where u.id = :id]]>
</query>
```

Than pass this list to jsp and iterate it

edit.jsp

```
<s:form action="update">
    <s:iterator id="lis" value="al">
        <s:hidden name="id" value="%{id}"></s:hidden>
        <s:textfield name="name" label="Name" value="%{name}"></s:textfield>
        <s:textfield name="city" label="City" value="%{city}"></s:textfield>
        <s:textfield name="pin" label="Pincode" value="%{pin}"></s:textfield>
        <s:submit value="Save"/>
    </s:iterator>
</s:form>
```

And than on this update action fire update code which you have already wrote. You also need to add edit action entry in `struts.xml` file:

```
<action name="edit" class="com.EditAction" method="edit">
    <result name="success">/edit.jsp</result>
</action>
```

You can also use `TraineeRegistration.jsp` instead of creating new jsp `edit.jsp` but sake of simplicity create new jsp.

Hope this helps!!!